# Continue the script if an element is not found

Tags: python, android, selenium, exception, appium

There are at least 2 more questions on the platform but none of their answers helped me.

I just imported:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

then used:

```
if Newest_tab_button:
    print('element found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

or

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    Newest_tab_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@text="NEWEST"]//ancestor::*[contains(@resource-id, "itemContainer")]')))
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Element not found')
```

Nothing worked, still got the:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch multiple Exceptions in the same `except` block or with multiple `except` block

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    Newest_tab_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@text="NEWEST"]//ancestor::*[contains(@resource-id, "itemContainer")]')))
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("TimeoutException")
    
except NoSuchElementException as e1:
    print("NoSuchElementException")
    
except Exception as e3: # To catch an Exception other than the specified once.
    print(e3)
```

Or you need to put all the Exceptions in a tuple:

```
except (TimeoutException,NoSuchElementException): # This catches either TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException
    print("ERROR")
```

Comment: First method works as a charm. 
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the second method, you're only catching `NoSuchElementException` but the issue is that your script is timing out and you're getting a `TimeoutException`, you just need to catch that too to continue the script

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    Newest_tab_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@text="NEWEST"]//ancestor::*[contains(@resource-id, "itemContainer")]')))
except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException) as error:
    print(error)
# Continue with the script
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for trying to help
I got: Python version 3.7 does not support this syntax and SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Claudaette I missed the parenthesis, the code should be fixed now.